# TypeError: chatHeading[0].style is not a function

Tags: javascript, css

I can't change a style of a div I used this code :

```
var chatHeading = $('#chatHeading');
console.log(chatHeading[0]);
chatHeading[0].style('background', item.color, 'important');
```

But it gives me the error: `TypeError: chatHeading[0].style is not a function`

Comment: Use [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) as an index, not [0], and use .css(), not style. You shouldn't be trying to access an index of one object, though, since you are accessing an element by **ID**, not class or tag.

Comment: Why not `chatHeading.css()` giving you are already using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try `css()` and `background-color`

```js
var chatHeading = $('#chatHeading');
console.log(chatHeading);
chatHeading.css('background-color', 'red', 'important');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chatHeading">chatHeading</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code `var chatHeading = $('#chatHeading');` only return 1 item because **you get by id**, so that dont treat as array.

Correct:

```
var chatHeading = $('#chatHeading');
 chatHeading.css('background', 'red', 'important');
```

```js
var chatHeading = $('#chatHeading');
console.log(chatHeading);
chatHeading.css('background', 'red', 'important');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='chatHeading'>Chart Heading</div>
<div id='chatHeading'>Chart Heading</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `chatHeading[0]` you get back the native DOM node from the jQuery object, which has a (read-only) `style` property that **is not a function**.

Instead, it's an object offering CSS properties as key-value pairs which you can simply assign:

```
chatHeading[0].style.background = item.color + '!important';
```